# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el nombre del enumerador a partir de su entero correspondiente en Vb.Net?

Tags: vb.net, .net

Necesitó crear una función en Vb.Net a la cual le pase un numero entero y me devuelva la parte de cadena

Tengo el siguiente enumerador:

```
Public Enum TipoAplicaEnum
    Ingreso = 1
    Egreso = 2
    Otro = 3
  End Enum
```

Ejemplo:

```
Dim strNombreEnum = ObtenerNombreTipoAplicaEnum(2)
‘strNombreEnum = “Egreso”
 
Public Function ObtenerNombreTipoAplicaEnum (ByVal intIndex)
‘ CODIGO NESESARIO
Return  “Egreso”
End Fuction
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar [CType](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/ctype-function) para castear

```
Function ObtenerNombreTipoAplicaEnum(intIndex)
    Return CType(intIndex, TipoAplicaEnum)
End Function
```

o más explicito

```
Function ObtenerNombreTipoAplicaEnum(intIndex) As String
    Return CType(intIndex, TipoAplicaEnum).ToString()
End Function
```